# Texture Displayed with Green Hue

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm learning how to apply textures in OpenGL. I have a fairly simple cube on which I am trying to apply a texture to make it look like a wooden board. When I apply my texture, it displays with a green hue. I can apply some other textures that look just fine, so I can't figure out what is wrong with this one. I created the texture from a jpg that I downloaded. The bmp file looks fine when I view it in Preview (I'm on a Mac). I'll attach a screenshot of the original bitmap and also of how it looks when rendered by OpenGL.

[image] [image]

The texture loading code that I am using can be found [here](https://github.com/davidwparker/opengl-3defense/blob/master/loadTexBMP.c):

```
unsigned int texture[2];  //  Texture names

// define the board
float square_edge       =    1;
float border            =  0.5;
float board_thickness   = 0.25;
float board_corner      = 4 * square_edge + border;
float board_width       = 2 * board_corner;

GLfloat board_vertices[8][3] = {
    {-board_corner,  board_corner, 0.0},
    {-board_corner, -board_corner, 0.0},
    { board_corner, -board_corner, 0.0},
    { board_corner,  board_corner, 0.0},
    {-board_corner,  board_corner, -board_thickness},
    {-board_corner, -board_corner, -board_thickness},
    { board_corner, -board_corner, -board_thickness},
    { board_corner,  board_corner, -board_thickness}
};

void polygon(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);  glVertex3fv(board_vertices[a]);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);  glVertex3fv(board_vertices[b]);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);  glVertex3fv(board_vertices[c]);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);  glVertex3fv(board_vertices[d]);
    glEnd();
}

void draw_board() {

    glPushMatrix();

    glRotatef(rotx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glScalef(1/board_corner, 1/board_corner, 1/board_corner);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, board_vertices);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); //color of the border, sides, bottom of board

    // draw the board
    polygon(0,3,2,1);
    polygon(2,3,7,6);
    polygon(0,4,7,3);
    polygon(1,2,6,5);
    polygon(4,5,6,7);
    polygon(0,1,5,4);

    glPopMatrix();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glLoadIdentity();

    double Ex = -2*dim*Sin(th)*Cos(ph);
    double Ey = +2*dim        *Sin(ph);
    double Ez = +2*dim*Cos(th)*Cos(ph);
    gluLookAt(Ex,Ey,Ez , 0,0,0 , 0,Cos(ph),0);

    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

    draw_board();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();    
}
```

Comment: If this is happening, the issue is most likely to do with either your lighting or the color of the object you're assigning this to. Make sure that the color of the object is white.

Comment: Can we see your texture loading code?  That PNG is RGB (no alpha) but perhaps you are loading it as an RGBA?

Comment: Sure. I edited my OP to include a link to a git repository with the same code.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @AlexBeisley that it may be a lighting issue (given glColor is already white), or colour masking. I'd try printing some of the bitmap values to the console to check they aren't actually green. Also, there's no `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` set, which can be an issue when loading non power of two RGB textures.

Comment: Thanks to everybody. I'm completely new to this, and at the moment very confused. I started with a jpg file, cropped it to 128x128 in Gimp, and then exported it is a a bmp file. How can it come out with a green hue? If this method won't work, what is the proper way to create a bmp file that I can read into OpenGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the bmp image itself. As I mentioned, I created this from a jpg file by converting it via Gimp. Somehow, this conversion went awry. When I run 'file wood.bmp' from the command line, my response is 'wood.bmp: data'. It should show 'wood.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 128 x 128 x 24" or something similar. I did the conversion using good ol' MS Paint, and the problem went away.

I'm trying to find out how to do this in Gimp, but for now this all works. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

When exporting a .bmp image with gimp, make sure you select the "Do not write color space information" option, underneath the Compatibility Options dropdown. .bmp images exported this way won't appear with a green hue when rendered with opengl.